# Typeform-like multi-step form animations in React

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, web

I'm trying to create a multi-step form for a booking process, and I want to create an animation like this https://www.typeform.com/templates/t/dessert-order-form-template/ , where an input remains fixed in the view for a certain amount of scrolling until it reaches a break-point and smooth-scrolls to the next container. I've been trying to find information on how to do this, but I don't quite know what it is that I'm exactly looking for and how to ask for it.

What adds to the complexity of my problem is that the one container's height is dynamic (a user can add inputs that increase its height). How could I factor this in?

I have a vague idea of how I could pull it off, using anchor tags to scroll to elements. But I don't know how to keep the container in a fixed position for a certain amount of scrolling, and I also don't know how to address the dynamic-sized component.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [scrollmagic](https://scrollmagic.io/)

[Splide.js](https://splidejs.com/) also could be useful if styled properly.

I personally think that scrollmagic is better for this but I've done quizes in splide so its definitely possible to style it similar.

Its also doable by yourself but Its hella lots of work. With additional libraries it can be faster.

There is a scrollmagic example [link](https://ihatetomatoes.net/5-days-with-scrollmagic/#scrollmagic-template-01), I found it in 2 min so if you google for some more examples you could find one more similar to yours

Also there is a video about simple pinning: [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PyJ5loyJnfE&ab_channel=Ihatetomatoes)

Comment: Ahh, so scroll pinning is what they call it. Thanks very much for the help! I reverse-engineered the Typeform page a bit and did some brainstorming; came up with a possible hand-made solution, but might not work out. This will come in super handy as an alternative. Thanks kindly.

Comment: No problem. Hope you find best way to do it! Happy coding :)